# WKWebView in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, uiwebview, wkwebview

It seems that the IB object templates in XCode 6 beta are still creating old-style objects (UIWebView for iOS and WebView for OSX).  Hopefully Apple will update them for the modern WebKit, but until then, what is the best way to create WKWebViews in Interface Builder?  Should I create a basic view (UIView or NSView) and assign its type to WKWebView?  Most of the examples I find online add it to a container view programmatically; is that better for some reason?

Comment: This is still an open bug: https://lists.webkit.org/pipermail/webkit-unassigned/2014-September/640090.html

Comment: I'm using Xcode 7.2, I don't see WKWebView in the object library.  Is it still not available?

Comment: Still not present in Xcode 8.

Comment: Xcode 9.0.1 now supports WKWebView in IB. All of the answers here are now deprecated.

Comment: @smileBot The new version of Xcode does have WKWebView but it requires you to target iOS 11+. crx_au answer works the best -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/40118654/757503

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You are correct - it doesn't seem to work. If you look in the headers, you'll see:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder NS_UNAVAILABLE;
```

which implies that you can't instantiate one from a nib.

You'll have to do it by hand in viewDidLoad or loadView.

Comment: Hopefully they will change that at some point, but I suppose it's not a big deal.  Johan pointed me back to the WWDC video, and even they are instantiating in code.

Comment: On the plus side, doing it in code will let you use UIWebView in iOS 7 and WKWebView in iOS 8.

Comment: Well after this answer, I think you can override this method in a subclass of WKWebView and then use it in interface builder.. but without super.initWithCoder.. let's test ! :)

Comment: After a personal test : you can't... "Cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable" too bad...

Comment: One reasonable thing to do might be to create a UIView subview called MyWebView that has either a WKWebView or a UIWebView as a subview, determined at runtime in initWithCoder. Then you can create MyWebView views in IB. If you are using Swift, you can even add properties that can be edited in IB using the IBInspectable keyword.

Comment: This is now possible in Interface Builder, by subclassing WKWebView. See answer from crx_au to this question. :)

Comment: This is now apparently fixed in Xcode 9b4. The release notes say "WKWebView is available in the iOS object library.".

Answer (score 66):

As pointed out by some, as of Xcode 6.4, WKWebView is still not available on Interface Builder. However, it is very easy to add them via code.

I'm just using this in my ViewController. Skipping Interface builder

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()

        //If you want to implement the delegate
        //webView?.navigationDelegate = self

        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let url = URL(string: "https://google.com") {
            let req = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView?.load(req)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is specifically about Interface Builder, so this answer isn't very helpful.

Comment: You are right. I should have started the answer with “You can't create WKWebView from IB" :)

But I watch the session video “Introducing the Modern WebKit API" from WWDC and they are using Xcode so I guess that this is just something that isn’t available to us at the moment.

Comment: Just checked out the video again, and they are instantiating their WKWebView in code.  It's around the 17:20 mark in the video.

Comment: Note from UIViewController loadView: "Your custom implementation of this method should not call super." Otherwise thanks for this post.

Comment: Adding a new view in the loadView method will create an infinite loop. Not recommended. Just add it as a subview in viewDidLoad.

Comment: How will it create an infinite loop? This is from description of loadView in the iOS documentation. "The view controller calls this method when its view property is requested but is currently nil."

Comment: For Swift3:    if let url = URL(string:"https://google.com") {
      let req = URLRequest(url:url)
      webView!.load(req)
    }

Comment: **_Referencing_** `self.view` inside `loadView()` is what leads to infinite recursion. **_Setting_** the view, on the other hand, is not only allowed but indeed **required** (manually, or by chaining to `super`. Otherwise it will keep being called as long as the view is `nil`).

Comment: Setting the web view as the view controller's main view (as opposed to adding it as a subview) has the added benefit that you don't need to specify any autoresizing masks or auto-layout constraints in order for it to fit the whole screen (or the view of the parent view controller).

Answer (score 30):

**Info.plist**

add in your Info.plist transport security setting

```
 <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
 </dict>
```

### Xcode 9.1+

> Using interface builder

You can find WKWebView element in the Object library.

[image]

> Add view programmatically with **Swift 5**

```
let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
view.addSubview(webView)
webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
```

> Add view programmatically with **Swift 5** (full sample)

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        initWebView()
        webView.loadPage(address: "http://apple.com")
    }

    private func initWebView() {
        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
        view.addSubview(webView)
        self.webView = webView
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        webView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}

extension WKWebView {
    func loadPage(address url: URL) { load(URLRequest(url: url)) }
    func loadPage(address urlString: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        loadPage(address: url)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a good suggestion to allocate a new view in the initializer for `WebView`. crx_au's response is superior

Comment: I dont found any other thing that works!!
So... as ILI4S said maybe it's not a good suggestion, i dont know if it's or not, but works properly!
Thanks man, you saved my day!!:)

Answer (score 21):

Here's a simple Swift 3 version based on **crx_au**'s excellent answer.

```
import WebKit

class WKWebView_IBWrapper: WKWebView {
    required convenience init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        //config.suppressesIncrementalRendering = true //any custom config you want to add
        self.init(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
}
```

Create a UIView in Interface Builder, assign your constraints, and assign it `WKWebView_IBWrapper` as a custom class, like so:

[image: Utilities -> Identity Inspector Tab[1]]

Comment: Excellent answer

Answer (score 20):

With Xcode 8 this is now possible, but the means of achieving it is a little hacky to say the least. But hey, a working solution is a working solution, right? Let me explain.

WKWebView's initWithCoder: is no longer annotated as "NS_UNAVAILABLE". It now looks as shown below.

```
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

Start by subclassing WKWebView and override initWithCoder. Instead of calling super initWithCoder, you'll need to use a different init method, such as initWithFrame:configuration:. Quick example below.

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    // An initial frame for initialization must be set, but it will be overridden 
    // below by the autolayout constraints set in interface builder. 
    CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    WKWebViewConfiguration *myConfiguration = [WKWebViewConfiguration new];

    // Set any configuration parameters here, e.g.
    // myConfiguration.dataDetectorTypes = WKDataDetectorTypeAll; 

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame configuration:myConfiguration];

    // Apply constraints from interface builder.
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    return self;
}
```

Over in your Storyboard, use a UIView and give it a custom class of your new subclass. The rest is business as usual (setting auto-layout constraints, linking the view to an outlet in a controller, etc).

Finally, WKWebView scales content differently to UIWebView. Many people are likely going to want to follow the simple advice in [Suppress WKWebView from scaling content to render at same magnification as UIWebView does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102908/suppress-wkwebview-from-scaling-content-to-render-at-same-magnification-as-uiweb) to make WKWebView more closely follow the UIWebView behaviour in this regard.

Comment: it should read `self = [super initWithFrame:myFrame configuration:myConfiguration];` also if you use constraints, don't forget to set `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;`

Comment: Rather than using the main screen's bounds as a placeholder frame, you may also us CGRectZero and save yourself some code.

Comment: Nice solution. Works well.

Comment: Works flawlessly! Nice fix for not having to Target iOS 11 to get WKWebView constraints in the storyboard.

Answer (score 6):

If you still face this issue in recent versions of Xcode, i.e. v9.2+, simply import Webkit to your ViewController:

```
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
```

1. Before the fix:
   [image]
2. After the fix:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is now apparently fixed in Xcode 9b4. The release notes say "WKWebView is available in the iOS object library."

I haven't looked deeper to see if it requires iOS 11 or is backward compatible yet.

Comment: I can confirm that this works! Hooray! It also works in macOS storyboards (at least for apps targeting macOS 10.13+).

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate and configure a WKWebView in IB since Xcode 9, no need to do it in code.
[image]

Note that your deployment target has to be higher than iOS 10 though or you will get a compile-time error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In XCode Version 9.0.1 WKWebView is available  on Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

I've linked WebKit, now it's working!

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but I solved the problem for me by including the WebKit framework for the target. Don't embed it just link the reference. I still use the WebView object in IB and drop it on the ViewController I'm embedding it in and I've never had a problem...

I've worked on 4 WKWebView MacOS projects now and the WebView has worked properly in each project.

Answer (score -15):

This worked for me in Xcode 7.2...

First add the web view as a UIWebView outlet in the storyboard / IB.  This will give you a property like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

Then just edit your code to change it to a WKWebView.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKWebView *webView;
```

You should also change the custom class to WKWebView in the Identity inspector.

Comment: I tried this with an OS X project - that doesn't work, so it must be special case for iOS.

Comment: What you do is just like type-cast. It can NOT change the webView's type at all.