# WKWebView not respecting width=device-width

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I'm loading a simple html string into a `WKWebView` and my objective is to have a full screen image in that webview.

The problem is that the image seems to be scaled twice as big as expected.

I simply load the `WKWebView` using

```
NSString *html = @"..."  // the content
[self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```

I'm expecting the image to be full screen and fit the screen

[image]

But I get an image that seems to be twice as big as the screen resolution (not the text at the bottom left(

[image]

I tried playing with using the `initial-scale` and `maximum-scale`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
```

But it does not work.

Also not that this seems to happen only for images that are base64 encoded in the HTML but this is something I need.

The HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
</head>

<img src="data:image/png;base64, ...">
<!-- <img src="http://placehold.it/750x1334"> -->
</body>
</html>
```

[Here is the html complete HTML](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/ckkfbvkusr3mw76/webview-test.html?dl=0)

Comment: You can use scaleToFit property of WebView to set the image inside the webView, so if your image is larger it will take full screen, i guess

Comment: There is not such a property on a `WKWebView`. There is a `scalesPageToFit` on a `UIWebView` if that's what you mean. I have to use `WKWebView` though

Comment: @Jan did you found a solution? I'm in trouble on the same issue...

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26720053/1197966) should solve the problem, let me know

Answer (score 12):

I added and it is working.

The HTML is:

```
      <html>
            <head>
                <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
                <style>
                    img {
                        width:auto;
                        height:auto;
                        max-width:100%;
                        max-height:90vh;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
        <body>
<!-- body container -->
        </body>
        </html>
```