# Is there a way to scale up a WKWebView?

Tags: swift

I'm using a WKWebView to load a html resource:

```
    func setUpWebView() {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "random", withExtension: "html") else { return }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(request)
}
```

The view is uploading the content of the html resource but is not scaled:
[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMJx0.png)

If I do the same with a UIWebView the resource is scaled (but uiwebview is deprecated)

Any idea?

edit1:

```
webView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```

This doesn't help.

Comment: Can you share code where to add your `webView` please?

Comment: I have solved the issue with this response: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102908/suppress-wkwebview-from-scaling-content-to-render-at-same-magnification-as-uiweb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions...tent-to-render-at-same-magnification-as-uiweb

Comment: The link doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add some additional settings to `webView`:

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

// Make sure your `self.view` already has final size
webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: webConfiguration)
webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
webView.uiDelegate = self
webView.scrollView.bounces = false

view.addSubview(webView)
```

I hope it will be useful to you