# Unable to add WKWebView to Xcode Project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, wkwebview

I have a ViewController that looks something like:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!
}
```

In my storyboard I have a `WKWebView` as a subview of my main view. I've linked up the IBOutlet but when I run the application I receive:

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x431)

[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong here and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WKWebView is not supported on Storyboards. You have to create it by code. The web view element you are using in your Storyboard is a UIWebView.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Not by Apple. But http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167812/wkwebview-in-interface-builder

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple and direct code to create and load your WKWebView:

```
        let webView = WKWebView(frame:NSMakeRect(0, 0,1000, 1000))
        webView.load(NSURLRequest(url:NSURL(string:"https://YourWebURLToLoad") as! URL) as URLRequest)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self;
        self.window.contentView?.addSubview(webView)
```