# Go back and forward in WebView using Screen Edge Pan Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview, uiwebview

I want to go back and forward in my iOS apps WebView using "Screen Edge Pan Gesture Recognizer" like in Apples mobile Safari browser. Best would be if animated like in Safari.

Currently I use "Swipe Gesture Recognizer" but it isn't very easy to use for the users. Especially it doesn't work if user has zoomed the webpage.

Does anybody have a sample code, a manual or any other help?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is WKWebView? I never heard of it. How can I add this?

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer. What will happen if I try to use WKWebView with an OS lower than iOS 8?

Comment: I've created separate answer from comments above, just to make sure that this information have proper visibility.

Answer (score 7):

This functionality is much easier to implement in `WKWebView`. You should simply set `allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures` property to `YES`.

`WKWebView` is a modern replacement for `UIWebView`, made by Apple. See [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/) for details. You should link with `WebKit.framework` to use it. Unfortunately there is no Interface Builder support, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167812/wkwebview-in-interface-builder).

Note that `WKWebView` available starting from iOS 8. Most likely you will receive crash on application start on earlier iOS versions. But it's possible to use `UIWebView` on pre-iOS 8, and `WKWebView` for iOS 8 and later. Take a look on [this github project](http://github.com/gowithfloat/FLWebView) as an example.