# Xcode Opening a WebView in another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I'm trying to make an app with a button which launch a webview.

I've followed many tutorial and read differents topic about the subject but I cant get it working : I'm getting this message when I test my code :

```
    "Cannot call value of non-function type UIWebView!"
```

Here's the steps I did until now

- Adding a button in the principal view Controller
- Creating an another view Controller named 'WebViewController'
- Adding a segue to link the button to WebViewController
- Creating a new Cocoa Touch Class file 'WebViewController'
- Setting the WebViewController custom class with the WebViewController class
- Adding a webView in the WebViewController ViewController named 'myWebView'

Here's the WebViewController class (in which I got the error when I run the project)

```
  import UIKit

  class WebViewController: UIViewController{

  @IBOutlet weak var myWebView: UIWebView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //define url
    let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.my-url.com")
    //request
    let req = NSURLRequest(url: url as! URL)
    //load request into the webview
    myWebview(req as URLRequest) //error happens here : 
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Here's a screenshot (picture talks more than long text, right =)
[image]

Thanks !

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39682344/swift-3-webview

Comment: Thanks @Anbu.Karthik ! Its working ! I dont know why but its definitely working !

Answer (score 2):

You can use SFSafariViewController:

```
import SafariServices

let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
let safariVC: SFSafariViewController = SFSafariViewController(url: url)

self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I used swift 3 syntax. 
That code opens a Safari Web view and you dont need to create segues and view controlles in storyboard.

Comment: You can set tint color, title and other properties to it. Hope it helps!

Comment: I'll try that later too ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
  let url = NSURL (string: "https://google.com")
  let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as! URL)
  self. myWebView.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)
```

This code works for me

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Im gonna try that later !