# How to stop WKWebView from autoplaying HTML5 videos?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

My attempt was to set `webView.configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = .video`

However, this does not work and after searching Google I was not able to find a workaround.

webView is an IBOutlet with a custom WKWebView class as follows:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ScrollWebView: WKWebView {


  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
    self.configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = .all
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback` is not a boolean. It's of type `WKAudiovisualMediaTypes`. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkaudiovisualmediatypes) is the Apple Documentation:

Try this:

```
webView.configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = .video
```

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong property name. Also, setting mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback to .video still does not work. As such, I've edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

After further research I realized that WKWebView cannot be configure nor created to a great extent in Storyboard or with Interface Builder. It must be created programatically. Reference: [WKWebView in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167812/wkwebview-in-interface-builder)

Configuration can be done at object creation time.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set these in a Storyboard:
[image]